# Pass values to another UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsstring

I am trying to pass values (UIImage, NSString) to another ViewController, but it wont work.

My code looks like this:

1st ViewController.m

```
#import 2nd ViewController.h

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    AppDetail *advc = [[AppDetail alloc] init];
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        advc.appTitel = name;
        advc.appIcon = icon;
        advc.detailAppName = detileName;
        advc.appDescription = description;
    }
}
```

2nd ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDetail : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *appTitel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *appIcon;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *detailAppName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *appDescription;

@end
```

2nd ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = self.appTitel;
    self.appIconImageView.image = self.appIcon;
    self.detailAppNameTextView.text = self.detailAppName;
    self.appDescriptionTextView.text = self.appDescription;
}
```

But I always get `(null)` for all values!

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct by this :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

       // Get reference to the destination view controller
        AppDetail *advcc = [segue destinationViewController];

        advc.appTitel = name;
        advc.appIcon = icon;
        advc.detailAppName = detileName;
        advc.appDescription = description;
    }
}
```

The code below it's when you don't use storyboard :

```
AppDetail *advc = [[AppDetail alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct these lines

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //AppDetail *advc = [[AppDetail alloc] init];
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        AppDetail *advc     = segue.destinationViewController; //ADD THIS
        advc.appTitel       = name;
        advc.appIcon        = icon;
        advc.detailAppName  = detileName;
        advc.appDescription = description;
    }
}
```